# Django pass variable from button to view

Tags: django

This is my template file which contains a menu that generates dynamically:

```
        {% block idfs %}
        {% for each in list %}
            <li>
                <a href="{{each}}">{{ each }}</a>
                <button type="submit" value={{each}} onclick="location.href='{{each}}'" name='{{each}}'>Go</button>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endblock %}
```

I have the button there, and I need the name for each button in my view. So when user clicks on any button, I can process the output in my view.

I have tried this in my view:

```
def example(request):
    item = request.POST.get('name')
    print(item)
```

But it doesn't work. It always returns None.
Shouldn't it work? Since I am using 'name' to pass the data from template? How can I pass the generated names in my buttons to my view?

Comment: Because you are making GET requests, not POST. Wrap your button in a form element, and set `method='POST'` and `action='{{each}}'`. You don't need `onclick` staff then.